# How to retrieve a particular key from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Database Image]

I have seen similar questions but none of the answers have helped me so far.
I have a user id key and in that for every post, I have a key and I want to implement the like feature for each post but when a try to retrieve the key for a particular post, I get the last key because the onChildAdded method is called for all the children once but I want the key of that particular post.

```
likeReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post").child(uid);
    likeReference.keepSynced(true);
    likeReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.i("onChildAdded", "Method invoked");
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            secondReference = likeReference.child(key);

            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });

    like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("Like:","Like clicked");
            if(post.isLiked()){
                post.setLiked(false);
                secondReference.child("liked").setValue(post.isLiked());
                like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up);
            }else{
                post.setLiked(true);
                secondReference.child("liked").setValue(post.isLiked());
                like.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you know the key of the post that you want write a like to?

Comment: If I want LJdRO7r8uh... how do I get it ? Right now whenever I like any post in the listview , change appears in the last one i.e. LJj0ZA60yza.....

Comment: Since you only have one `secondReference`, it will always point to the last snapshot that was passed to `onChildAdded`. If you want to set the `liked` on the correct post, how do you know what post that is?

Comment: So I need the position of that item in the listview .

Comment: How do I do that ?